# Convergence of series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\big(1-\frac{1}{k}\big)^{k^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\bigg(1-\frac{1}{k}\bigg)^{k^2}$$
I know that the series converges to $$1/e$$ but I can't prove it.
Any tips?

Comment: The given series does *not* converge to $1/e$.

Comment: Root test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the root test:
$$\lim_{k\to \infty} \sqrt[k]{\left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^{k^2}}=\lim_{k\to \infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{k}\right)^k=\frac1e<1.$$

The series converges, but to $0.10...$ ([reference](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bk%3D1%7D%5E%5Cinfty%5Cbigg(1-%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bk%7D%5Cbigg)%5E%7Bk%5E2%7D)).

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**. To prove the *convergence* of the given series one may use that
$$
1-\frac1n\leq e^{-1/n},\qquad \qquad n=1,2,\cdots,
$$ then
$$
0\le\left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}\leq e^{-n}.
$$ Observe that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(1-\frac1n\right)^{n^2}=0.1045\cdots <\color{red}{\frac1e=0.3678\cdots}.
$$

Comment: It may be worth mentioning in your answer that the limit is not (in spite of the OP's belief) $e^{-1}$.

Comment: @ClementC. Edited, thanks.

Comment: That was my mistake about where the series converges.